# how much php coding do i need to know in order to create web blog using wordpress.org

Tags: php

I want to create web blog using WordPress so in order for me to create that blog, what level of php coding do I need to know. At the moment, I'm just learning the basis of php

I kind of started designing the blog but just could not get around the PHP coding bit so just wondered weather I need or not

Can I create the blog without using PHP coding so please I need some advice on weather I must use PHP to create the blog or does not matter if I use or not.

Comment: Millions of people use WordPress without any coding knowledge whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

It depends of what you're trying to accomplish. If you only want to install WP and add a theme and some plugins, it will be really easy to do so. If you do this and only want to make some adjustments, you could easily google what you need, because there is a lot of documentation around PHP.

If you're trying to code your own WP theme, things get nastier. To make it easier for you, download some existing themes and check out the code in them. Most of code will be HTML and CSS, because PHP is only used to generate the dynamic content, like posts, comments, sidebar contents etc.

You could just create the HTML and CSS for your theme and get the PHP parts from an existing theme.

You can read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) about theme development and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) you have the PHP manual.

Here you have a list of themes used as boilerplate for development: [1](http://html5blank.com/), [2](http://speckyboy.com/2010/03/22/10-blanknaked-wordpress-themes-perfect-for-development/).